# Number Separator in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line in a repeater in my ASP.NET web page:

```
<%# Eval(123456) %>
```

I want to shown my number (123456) with separator (like this: 123,456)

what I must to do ?

I know something about string format. and I use some string format like "{N3}" and "{#,000)"
 . but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", 123456);
```